# MYSQL where clause slow performance on big table

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a performance issue when working with a huge table

I add index on column using this :

```
 ALTER table add index column;
```

and on the text/blob column :

```
alter table  add index (cat(200));
```

My table has about 6M rows and i am working with InnoDB engine (Mysql 5.5)

This query is very fast now that i add index on "order by" column:

```
  SELECT * from table order by column DESC LIMIT 0,40
```

But when I add a WHERE clause on this query its very slow and it take about 10 seconds to load even with the column "cat" index like above. `//index instead of indexed`

```
 SELECT * from table WHERE cat = 'electronic' order by column DESC LIMIT 0,40
```

the EXPLAIN of this slow query :

```
  EXPLAIN SELECT * from table WHERE cat = 'electronic' order by 'id' DESC LIMIT 0,40
```

id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : product
type : ref
possible_keys: cat
key: cat
Key_len: 203
ref: const
row : 1732184
extra: using where

The query working fine with small table with 50k rows but with 6M rows its slow. Why?

Comment: is `cat` indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use prefixing, such as `cat(200)`; it *usually* makes the index unusable.  I have never seen a case where the Optimizer, when faced with `INDEX(a(10), b)`, gets past `a` and makes any use of `b`.

Change `cat` to be `VARCHAR(255)`.  That is probably more than sufficient for "categories".

The best index (if it is possible) is

```
INDEX(cat, `column`)
```

Note that `cat` is in the `WHERE` with `=`.  It handles the entire `WHERE`, so the index can move on to the `ORDER BY`.  Hence `column` can be used, too.  [*More discussion of index making*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

If `cat` must be `TEXT`, then the best you can do is

```
INDEX(`column`)
```

Then the Optimizer *may* decide to use it for avoiding a filesort.  But if there are fewer than 40 (see `LIMIT`) 'electronic' rows, it will take an big scan and probably be slower than not using the index.  So, I am not sure that it is even worth having `INDEX(column)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply sir After testing I saw that index on int(11) work very well and fast so I am creating another column right now and every "electronic" will be "100" , every "food" will be "200" etc... I am trying this not sure if its gonna be ok WIll see :)

Comment: `VARCHAR` (up to 255) will work almost as fast as `INT`.  Also, `ENUM` will work fast.  `TEXT` is the troublemaker.

Comment: Great I dint know that Thanks a lot Sir !

Comment: Fantastic ! I change cat column from text to varchar 255 work like a charm Thanks a million time Sir !

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE cat = 'electronic'
ORDER BY column DESC
LIMIT 0, 40;
```

The best index is a composite index on `table(cat, column)`.  You can use a prefix if `column` is too wide:  `table(cat, column(200))`.

Comment: I dont get it sorry

Comment: column is a reserved word?

Comment: column on table like "id" "idnumber" "date" :)

Comment: No, do not use "prefix indexing" ("column(200)").  It is as bad as not having the index.  (Or at least it was useless in my similar test case.)

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to index the table, if you dont know how to do it, you can check [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)
So, when you perform the query, the mysql will start searching on the indexed values, skipping a lot of useless data for that request.